# On a variable addition test

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I'm having some difficulties in understanding the Variable addition test as is described in the pictures below.

My small doubt is how can we have the same error term in equation (3.7.4) and (3.7.5)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not see any place where it is asserted that the error terms are the "same."  Could you elaborate on your understanding of what "the same" means?

Comment: @whuber You're right. But question 2 from the third picture confuses me... the numerical equality should be verified even if the null is false? Or even if the null is true, the residuals by performing OLS on 3.7.4,  or on 3.7.5, will still be different?
Under the null, the residuals of both equations will tend to the same, since under the null the error term is the same, no?